# Can You Use Dojo.Build and a CDN at the Same Time?

Tags: javascript, dojo, cdn

Is it possible to use the Dojo build system to create a single file containing all the files you need for a web app but also include dojo from a CDN on the same page? Th CDN would act as a fallback, providing any dojo, dijit or dojox modules not included in the built file?

This would combine the speed of using dojo.build and the flexiility of being able to add new dojo.require() calls to the app without running dojo.build again.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want is the flexibility of extra require calls without having to build again then you don't *need* a CDN as the build system already handles this case for you. From the [docs](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/build/):

> _4. Finally, it copies all non-layered scripts to the appropriate places.
>   While this doesn't speed anything up, it ensures that all Dojo modules
>   can be loaded, even if not present in a layer. If you use a particular
>   module only once or twice, keeping it out of the layers makes those
>   layers load faster.

You just need to make sure those modules are required in a way that doesn't cause them to be included in your main layer. You can do this either explicitely in the build profile or implicitely by using a different calling syntax on the require function so that it cannot be resolved at compile time.